# Cloud Functions - Cloud Firestore error: can't get serverTimestamp

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Cloud Functions - Cloud Firestore error: can't get serverTimestamp

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    exports.userlog = functions.firestore
    .document('user/{userId}')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => 
    { 
        const db = admin.firestore();
        //var timestamp = db.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
        var timestamp = db.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
        ...
        return db.collection('userlog').add(
        {
            userId : previousValue.userId,
            ...
            timestamp: timestamp
        }).then(ref => 
        {
            return console.log('Added document with ID: ', ref.id);
        });
    });
```

I got two errors separately:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'serverTimestamp' of undefined
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'TIMESTAMP' of undefined

Comment: Did you figure out how to solve this? I tried the suggested answer you received but it doesn't work. I get the same serverTimestamp error as you

Answer (score 22):

The correct syntax is:

```
firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

Note the lack of parenthesis (`()`) after `firestore`: this is a static variable, not an instance variable/member field.

Comment: where should we import `firebase` from?

Comment: @Re'em from ``` import firebase from 'firebase'```

Answer (score 3):

```
// Imports: Dependencies
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

// Correct Syntax (If You Don't Want To Import Firestore)
created_at: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score 1):

*since @FrankvanPuffelen's edit queue is full with missing imports, documentation, etc I'll post an update on his solution*

---

include from (web version 8):

```js
const firebase = require('firebase-admin');
```

or use more recent (web version 9):

```js
import {FieldValue} from "firebase/firestore";
```

---

The correct syntax is:

```js
firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

Note the lack of parenthesis (`()`) after `firestore`: this is a static variable, not an instance variable/member field.

See [Firebase example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#server_timestamp) for more info

Answer (score 0):

I was using the correct syntax as per the upvoted answer(s), but still go this error. It turns out it had something to do with my version of the `firebase` CLI being off-sync with versions of the `firebase-admin` package (I'm not sure how it happened in the first place, but I noticed form my source tracking tool that the package.json and lock files had been updated).

Solved the problem by deleting all changes I had made on my package.json & lock files and re-installed the CLI:

`npm i -g firebase-tools`